# Iterators in C++. How to modify a vector knowing its iterators?

Tags: c++, iterator

Trying to understand iterators in C++. For example, in the code below we print a vector.

```
using Iterator = vector<int>::iterator;

void PrintRange(Iterator range_begin, Iterator range_end) {
    for (auto it = range_begin; it != range_end; ++it) {
        cout << *it << " ";
    }
}

int main() {
    vector<int> numbers = {5, 3, 2, 1};
    PrintRange(begin(numbers), end(numbers));
    return 0;
}
// 5 3 2 1
```

My question is how to properly write a function *that takes only two iterators and that modifies the vector*. For example, the function my_sort sorts a vector and if we write

```
my_sort(begin(numbers), end(numbers));
```

number contains a modified sorted vector.

```
void my_sort(Iterator range_begin, Iterator range_end) {
    // how to modify a vector knowing its iterators ?
}
```

Comment: `cout << *it << " ";` -- The answer is right there in the code you have now.  You dereference the iterator and assign to it, i.e. `*it = whatever;`

Comment: `int tmp = *it1; *it1 = *it2; *it2 = tmp;` when you want to swap two values, or simply `std::swap(*it1, *it2);`

Comment: a `sort` is probably going to `swap(*it1, *it2)` somewhere

Comment: `std::iter_swap` is your friend. Especially if certain ADL related idioms are not yet known to you

Comment: BTW look into [std::sort](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) You may assume that iterator is an object version of a plain old C pointer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How to modify a vector knowing its iterators?

You can indirect through an input iterator to access the element that it points to. Example:

```
auto it = std::begin(numbers);
*it = 42;
```

> For example, the function my_sort sorts a vector

A sorting function generally swaps elements around. You can swap to elements pointed by iterators like this:

```
std::iter_swap(it1, it2);
```